# Creating OR capability with Slim Framework

Tags: php, mysql, api, slim

I have a slim GET method setup whose basic signature looks like this:

```
$app->get('/musicians/name/:name', function($name) use ($allFields, $app, $db)
```

I then create some query text, something along the lines of this:

```
$queryText = "SELECT date, bio, articles FROM Musicians WHERE name = :name"
```

I then proceed to bind the :name parameter to the $name variable introduced when the function was called.

This works fine and dandy, but what happens if I want to allow users to search for more than one musician at once? Is there a way I can get users to put in something in the URL that would translate my `$queryText` to something along the lines of `"SELECT date, bio, articles FROM Musicians WHERE name = 'Beethoven' OR 'Bach' OR 'The Sex Pistols'"?`

Note: I'm using PDO for database handling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it:

```
$queryText = "SELECT date, bio, articles 
              FROM Musicians 
              WHERE name = :name or name = :name1 or name = name2";
```

Then you can Bind each value separately or using an array of values.

Update:

You can use name1&name2&name3 in the url, then, you can use:

```
<?php
$names = explode("&", $querystring); //$querystring here is name1&name2&name3
//now names is an array contains all keywords
//lets build the query
$i = 1;
foreach($names as $name){
 $where[] = "name = :name$i";
 $params[":name$i"] = $name;
 $i++;
}
$queryText = "SELECT date, bio, articles 
              FROM Musicians 
              WHERE ".implode(" OR ", $where);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($queryText);
$sth->execute($params);
?>
```

Comment: Two problems with this: (1) this is user input and I won't know how many names they are supplying, so providing a fixed length name = :name OR name = :name2 would be problematic; and (2) with this approach, it seems like I would have to create a very deep URL for users looking for more than one name, i.e., musicians/name1/name2/name3/name4, where I'd rather just have something like musicians/name1ORname2ORname3ORname4.

Comment: And I don't think letting the users input the OR statements into the URL would work either, because I'm using PDO prepared statements, which I believe will escape OR statements for security.